# difference between two python interpreters

Tags: python, environment, apple-m1

I'm setting a python environment for new M1 mac(newbie of MacOS).

What I've done is installing Xcode, VScode, homebrew, and python3 in VScode installing extensions.

Then I tried to build some python project, and i met two interpreters with same version.

Python 3.8.2 with local one and Xcode's.

[image]

I'm afraid of two python interpreters mixing each other like anaconda python and local one(what i've faced in Windows).

Can I delete one to prevent further problem? Or I really don't have to?

Comment: You don't have to delete anything - in fact if you don't know where they are from, you should not! You might want to check whether these aren't even identical, e.g. symlinks.

Answer (score -1):

What I usually do is setup a `virtualenv` for the project and point VSCode at the `virtualenv`'s Python interpreter.

```
~/dev/project $ virtualenv venv
```

In VSCode: `CMD+Shift+P` => `Python: Select interpreter`

[image: Python: Select interpreter]

The list of interpreters should inclue the one inside the newly created `venv`:

[image: List of available Python interpreters]

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments